creating a symmetry shading with vega-lite (vega) similar to the scatter chart of Power BI
I'm wondering if someone can guide to an idea, the algorithm, an example of how to create Power BI's symmetry shading for scatter charts (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-scatter?tabs=powerbi-desktop#add-analytics-to-your-chart)
This
{
  "width": 600,
  "height": 600,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"ID": "I", "xVal": 3, "yVal": 2},
      {"ID": "I", "xVal": 4, "yVal": 6},
      {"ID": "II", "xVal": 3, "yVal": 3}
    ]
  },
  "mark": {
    "type": "circle"
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "xVal", "type":"quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": [0, 7]}
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "yVal", "type":"quantitative",
      "scale": {"domain": [0, 7]}
    }
  }
}

can looks like this

in Power BI, with the feature symmetry shading enabled.
I'm interested in how to draw the "shapes", being more precise, and getting/creating the coordinates of the shapes.
Any ideas?

Have you looked at voronoi? https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/transforms/voronoi/

I did, but at the moment I'm looking for a vega-lite based solution, because turning to vega comes with some complexities I want to avoid.

Drawing the shapes is easy enough but I think you'll struggle to find a way to write an algorithm to compute the coordinates using just VL. If you do, please let us know how!

Is the chart always split in two or could there be more than two shaded areas. If it is always two, you could use the linear regression to compute the coordinates.

To be honest, I do not know if there are always two areas I will play around a little. Thank you for pointing me to linear regression.
Next to thatm it's not only VL it's VL + DAX. I'm creating some kind of template that already contains some complex DAX. Some of the colleagues are used to DAX and M. But not familiar with Vega or Vega-Lite for this reason I want to stick to VL

I came up with a slightly different solution,
there is a background rect based on the data,
then there is a regression line and also an area chart.
I use the linear interpolation for the area chart and also the regression transform.
I'm sure that this could be done more simply, but I'm happy now :-)
The scatter chart looks like this:

the code that works in the vega-lite editor:
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 600,
  "height": 600,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"ID": "I", "xVal": 125, "yVal": 55, "size": 80},
      {"ID": "II", "xVal": 673, "yVal": 297, "size": 30},
      {"ID": "III", "xVal": 500, "yVal": 160, "size": 50}
    ]
  },
  "transform":[
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
          {"op": "max", "field": "yVal", "as": "maxyVal"},
          {"op": "min", "field": "yVal", "as": "minyVal"},
          {"op": "max", "field": "xVal", "as": "maxxVal"},
          {"op": "min", "field": "xVal", "as": "minxVal"}
        ]
    }
  ],
  "params": [
    {"name": "maxY", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['maxyVal'] "},
    {"name": "minY", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['minyVal'] "},
    {"name": "maxX", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['maxxVal'] "},
    {"name": "minX", "expr": "data('data_0')[0]['minxVal']  "}
  ],
  "title": "Power BIs Symmetry Shading and the Ratio Line now in Deneb",
  "layer": [
        { "description": "the area left/above",
        "mark": {
          "type":"rect",
          "color": "lightgray",
          "tooltip": {"content": "data" }
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "datum": {"expr": "minX"},
            "type": "quantitative",
            "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, maxX]"}}
          },
          "y": {
            "datum": {"expr": "0"},
            "type": "quantitative",
            "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, maxY]"}}
          },
          "x2": {"datum": {"expr": "maxX"}},
          "y2": {"datum": {"expr": "maxY"}}
        }  
      },

        { "description": "the area below right/below",
          "mark": {
          "type":"area",
          "interpolate": "linear",
          "color": "yellow",
          "tooltip": {"content": "data" }
        },
        "transform": [
            {
              "regression": "yVal",
              "on": "xVal"
            }
        ],
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "xVal",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, maxX]"}}
          },
          "y": {
            "field": "yVal",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, maxY]"}}
          }
        }  
        },
        { "description": "the  regression line",
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "color": "firebrick",
            "opacity": 0.4
          },
          "transform": [
            {
              "regression": "yVal",
              "on": "xVal"
            }
          ],
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "field": "xVal",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, maxX]"}}
            },
            "y": {
              "field": "yVal",
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, maxY]"}}
            }
          }
        },
        { "description": "the ALL bubble",
          "mark": {
            "type":"circle",
            "opacity": 0.2,
            "color":"blue",
            "tooltip": {"content": "data"}
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"aggregate":"mean", "field": "xVal","scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, maxX]"}}},
            "y": {"aggregate":"mean", "field": "yVal", "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, maxY]"}}},
            "size": {
              "aggregate":"sum", 
              "field":"size", 
              "legend": null
            }
          }
        },
        { "description": "all the bubbles",
          "mark": {
            "type":"circle",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "tooltip": true
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {"field":"xVal", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, minX]"}},
            "axis": {"title": null, "grid":false}},
            "y": {"field": "yVal", "type": "quantitative", "scale": {"domain": {"expr": "[0, maxY]"}},
            "axis": {"title": null, "grid":false}},
            "size": {
              "field":"size", 
              "type": "quantitative",
              "scale": {"rangeMax": 50000}
            },
            "color": {"field":"ID", "legend": null}
          }
        }           
  ]
}


Please refer to a similar answer here.
I simply make an area chart in the bottom section and fill the top section with the config background color.
The symmetry shade in PBI is just a line that splits the chart in half when the x and y axis are the same.
Let us know how you get along.

{
  "width": 500,
  "height": 500,
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"ID": "I", "xVal": 3, "yVal": 2},
      {"ID": "I", "xVal": 4, "yVal": 6},
      {"ID": "II", "xVal": 3, "yVal": 3}
    ]
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {"values": [{"ID": 1, "Start": 0}, {"ID": 2, "Start": 7}]},
      "encoding": {
        "y": {
          "field": "Start",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": "", "format": ".0f"}
        },
        "x": {
          "field": "Start",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"title": "", "format": ".0f"}
        }
      },
      "layer": [{"mark": {"type": "area", "fill": "#d5c9ed"}}]
    },
    {
      "mark": {"type": "circle", "size": 180, "fill": "#2d92fa"},
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {"value": 1},
        "x": {
          "field": "xVal",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "grid": false,
            "format": ".0f",
            "values": {"expr": "[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]"}
          },
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 7]}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "yVal",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "grid": false,
            "format": ".0f",
            "values": {"expr": "[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]"}
          },
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 7]}
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "config": {"view": {"fill": "#d2b3d7"}}
}


Hey, I'm wondering if I miss something about the link in your answer pointing to a similar answer, it looks like it points to my visual

Hi @TomMartens, Sorry fixed now. The links got messed up when I updated the image.

Hey @APB Reports, I posted an answer that is using a rect for the background instead of the view fill and I used the regression transform for the area mark, the area "below" the regression line.

Hi @TomMartens That isn't a symmetry line though? My answer was based on that request. Glad it worked out for you anyway.
